# Calculus of Variations by Charles Fox: Question on Statement in Section 2.4

Tags: functional-analysis, calculus-of-variations, variational-analysis

Fox states in Section 2.4, pg. 38, that

*"Anticipating this result, it follows that even if $u(x)$ vanishes at either or both of the values $x=a$ and $x=b$, both $t^2(a)/u(a)$ and $t^2(b)/u(b)$ still vanish since $t(a)=t(b)=0$ by hypothesis."*

How does this make sense? The quotient would become $0/0$ in such a case, which is indeterminate, not vanishing.

Comment: @Cesareo Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm just going to assume the Jacobi *Necessary* Condition is only looking at the internal interval $(a,b)$ and call it a day.

EDIT 3-25-19:

This is true (the necessary condition looks only at the open interval). Hence, Fox's statement is ultimately incorrect IFF $u$ were to equal $0$ at any point, but this is not possible (see [Difficulty Understanding Sufficient Conditions for Weak Extrema in Calculus of Variations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3155772/difficulty-understanding-sufficient-conditions-for-weak-extrema-in-calculus-of-v/3162339#3162339)).